# How can I create a click event where I have several div's and each having a button with the same Id but when clicked only affect the parent div, how?

Tags: javascript, html

My main issue is that I don't wan't to write several lines of code(javascript) or even repeat myself,
the code looks something like this

```
  <div class="main-div">
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
  </div>
```

now I would like add event listeners to the id 'myBtn' so that if it is clicked the sub-parent div which has the class of 'myDiv' will scale twice and position at the center increase in height but that is not important, my main focus is how would I use the javascript to only select the sub-div where the button is located rather than to select the whole div's and how will I do so with fewer lines of code?
or how more informative should I be?

Comment: ID's should be unique in HTML ... that said `document.querySelectorAll('#myBtn')` will give you a NodeList with all those buttons

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: what's wrong with that way?

Comment: for example I would like to know if it is the button on the 4th child without having to change the id names or maybe a way were the can have different id names but I will also have fewer lines of javascript? either way I am aiming for a time saving approach.

Comment: example adding a class to the div that it is in rather than every div there is

Comment: well, do you need to know its poisition relative to others, or just which one you clicked

Comment: sorry for that, I just want to know which one I clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to target an ancestor of one of your buttons while staying DRY, is using a global event-handler in conjunction with the [`element.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method.

```js
// pro-tip: instead of window choose an appropriate common ancestor as event-target
// this prevents unnecessary work by the browser, improving performance
window.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  // select the closest ancestor of our click-target with the `myBtn`-class
  const btn = target.closest('.myBtn');
  
  // if we didn't click on a button, `btn` is null and we do nothing
  // this prevents triggering on clicks we don't care about
  if (btn) {
    // add the `clicked`-class to the parent of the button
    btn.parentElement.classList.add('clicked');
  } 
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
  </div>  
  
  <div class="main-div">
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
     <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn">click me</button> </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I wanted but can you explain a little more about it because i think I am going to be using it more often.

Comment: Adding a click event on a `window` function - Not a good idea.

Comment: @bethropolis I added some comments to help you understand what is going on

Comment: @AlwaysHelping While you're absolutely right, `window` was the easiest choice working off the provided code and requirements.

Comment: @bethropolis You're welcome. If my answer solved your issue, you should accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an event handler around the parent div and then catch your child button hence do with them what you like

```
 document.querySelector('.main-div').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   console.log(e.target)
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll` method along with forEach method to get all button using your class. Also, for better `coding` practice element `id's` must be unique. `Simple` and `time` saving approach:

Also, do not use window `eventListener` as they are global and can affect other thing element on your page. Attach an event listeners to the acutal button instead.

Use `toggle` method to `remove` and `add` class your `myDiv` using `e.target.parentElement`

**Demo:**

```js
let getButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn') //get all buttons
getButtons.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) { //attach eventListener
    e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('myClass') //add Class
  })
})
```

```css
.myDiv {
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0.2em;
}

.myClass {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn1">click me</button> </div>
  <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn2">click me</button> </div>
  <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn3">click me</button> </div>
  <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn4">click me</button> </div>
  <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn5">click me</button> </div>
  <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" id="myBtn6">click me</button> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This creates a new function for each of the relevant elements, which is rather wasteful.

Comment: @AndreNuechter Its NOT wasteful it gives the Idea to OP to use `#mybtn` as id selector with `querySelectorAll`  since he really insist he want keep the id's same -  posted to give an idea to OP how this can be done which will help OP in future as well.

Comment: I commend your intentions, but the memory footprint of your approach is certainly larger than one created by using event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `parentNode`.

```
 <div class="main-div">
    <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" onclick="myFunc(this.parentNode)">click me</button> </div>
    <div class="myDiv"> <button class="myBtn" onclick = "myFunc(this.parentNode)">click me</button> </div>
</div>
 
<script>
     function myFunc(DIV) {
         //Your JS code goes here.....
     }
 </script>
```